# Is JCE part of Java SE 6?

Tags: java, jce

I am trying to use some open source java library and that library has JCE as one of its dependencies. If I am using Java 1.6, do I need to download a JCE library separately or is it part of it? Seems like bountycastle.org (the open source provider for JCE) does not have any JCE listed for 1.4+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JCE is bundled with JavaSE as of 1.4, according to [JCA's documentation...](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Introduction).

> **Notes on Terminology**
>
> Prior to JDK 1.4, the JCE was an unbundled product, and as such, the JCA and JCE were 
>   regularly referred to as separate, distinct components. As JCE is now bundled in the 
>   JDK, the distinction is becoming less apparent. Since the JCE uses the same 
>   architecture as the JCA, the JCE should be more properly thought of as a part of the
>   JCA.

Comment: Note that by default you are limited to 128-bit keys. For larger keys you need the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.

https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jce_policy-6-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is part of Java 6.